# Blue moving bar in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know what the blue moving line (from left to right) in Visual Studio Code means?

[image]

It appears relatively often, especially when reactivating from hibernation mode. Looks like some background processes are currently active.
Once the bar shows, it doesn't go away until I restart the program.

Comment: Maybe more importantly is there a way to see what the task/process is that is causing it to show/run? I personally don't mind it, but I want to see the log of what it is trying to do when it does show up. Is it possible to see it in console or elsewhere? This could give insight as to why it is appearing.

Answer (score 20):

It should be possible to make it transparent:

Put this into `settings.json`:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "progressBar.background": "#fff0",
}
```

Comment: My OCD thanks you for this.  :-)

Answer (score 12):

This occurs because when you try to find some file or functions which are not available, VsCode continues to keep trying to get that function and redirect cursor over there. So the loader stays there forever. The solution is to make VsCode look for something which it can find.

Just ctrl+click on any function which is available. Also you can ctrl+click on function where it is defined itself so it will directly point on it and loader will be removed.

For example you have below function

```
public function GetUSer(){

}
```

So just ctrl+click on `GetUser` and the loader will vanish.
No need to restart VsCode

Edit for js users :

Let say you have defined a variable :

```
var userName = 'Test';
```

And you have used it somewhere in the code

```
var userNameLength = userName.length
```

So just ctrl+click on `userName` where we get the length. It will go to defination (where the variable is defined) and the progress bar will be gone.

Comment: This did not work for me, at least in js code. It wouldn't look up other things either, because it was still stuck looking for the first thing. I had to restart it.

Comment: Ctrl-Click on a function is a good work around; worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 10):

Like previous answer said it is a loading indicator which occurs when vscode is attempting to look something up like a function definition or trying to lint.

You cannot hide it that I am aware of but you can get it to go away obviously by relaunching vscode. It is also limited to the current editor window so you can split your editor and then close the one with the indicator.

Comment: "It is also limited to the current editor window so you can split your editor and then close the one with the indicator." @tyhunt99 thank you this worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

That is a loading indicator. It happens when something is loading or is in process. It might be constantly refreshing the file tree because of changes in the directory

Comment: Anyway to hide it? Lol every once in a while you Ctrl+Click on a function or something and it launches into a never-ending search for the function definition and it just stays there, even if you go find it manually

Comment: @BrianLeishman Sorry no answer, but yeah seems like it maybe taxes ones computer a bit. Do you know if it slows things down or kills battery faster? seems like it slows things down after running for a while.

Comment: Sometimes its infinite and very anoying!

Comment: Hasn't anybody reported this in VSCode issue trackers? Strange!

Answer (score 0):

With [VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/51d664f3442cc4f63821a9ab65e487374c9d7efe/release-notes/v1_52.md#progress-for-long-running-operations-in-explorer), that moving bar should be more explicit (and cancellable!)

> ### Progress for long running operations in Explorer

> We now show progress in the Explorer and Status bar for long running File operations (longer than 500ms).
>
> There is also an inital support for cancelling these long running operations.
>
> This should be particularly helpful when copying large folders or downloading resources from remote.
>
> [image: Explorer Progress -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_52/explorer-progress.gif]
> <sup>(Click on the picture to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: I didn't see a way to cancel it in VS Code, unfortunately. Had to restart the program. I'm running v1.58.2. I think I was hung on a linting operation, though... not a file operation.

Comment: @rotarydial Strange, considering there is a button cancel in the animation.

Answer (score -3):

Perform the below changes in Visual Studio Code preferences settings

1. Disable Auto update
2. Disable Auto update of extensions
3. Disable error reporting service