# What is this running line below the menu bar in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Periodically I see the running line below my VSCode menu bar. At first I thought it was a software update or telemetry but I've disabled these features.

[image]

So what is it and how can I turn it off?

Comment: a progress/busy feedback

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53766557/12332424